# Evaluate variable in context

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a django context `C` and I want to evaluate a variable `var` in C (without dealing with templates), what to do ?

```
class PersonClass: pass
p = PersonClass
p.name = 'Test'

C = Context({"person": p})
# let's say I want to evaluate person.name

evaluate(C, 'person.name') should give 'Test' # like {{person.name}} in template would give Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work:

```
>>> C = Context({"person": p})
>>> C.get("person")
<class '__main__.PersonClass'>
>>> C.get("person").name
'Test'
```

EDIT: A more generic version:

```
def get_attr_from_context(ctx, attr_str):
    attrs = iter(attr_str.split('.'))
    ans = ctx.get(next(attrs))
    for attr in attrs:
        ans = getattr(ans, attr)
    return ans

# Prints 'Test'
print(get_attr_from_context(C, 'person.name'))
```

Comment: this is not generic. right ? You just hardcoded it for `person / name` I am looking for a more general function

Comment: This only works for attribute lookup. Django template language can also do dictionary and numeric index lookups.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the Django template language to resolve the variables.

Otherwise, you will have to recreate all of the functionality that Django provides (dictionary lookup, attribute lookup ...) which would be complicated and error prone.

```
from django.template.base import Variable, Context

def resolve_variable(variable, context_dict):
    """
    Resolve variable using the given dictionary context_dict 
    """
    return Variable(variable).resolve(Context(context_dict))

>>> resolve_variable('person.name', {'person': {'name': 'Ninja420'}})
'Ninja420'
```

Note, I believe Variable is a private API, so it's possible (but not likely) that this could break in a future version of Django.